# UINavigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO doesn't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `HomeViewController` and it has a property `searchViewController`.

`HomeViewController` is the delegate of `searchViewControllerDelegate` so that I can pop `searchViewController` when I click a button in `searchViewController.view` (I use `pushViewControllerAnimated:` to push `searchViewController` into view controller stack.

I want to show the `navigationBar` when the `searchViewController` is popped up.

However

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
```

is definitely not working.

I've checked that the navigationBar is not `nil` so I can't figure out what the problem might be.

**actual code**

```
#pragma mark - HomeTabSearchTableViewDelegate
-(void)parentViewControllerPop{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

**`searchViewController` is popped up successfully, just the navigationBar problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your `HomeViewController`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];   //shows  

    //or use like
   // [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];    // hides

      //or use like
   // [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Actually I've tried what you do in `viewWillAppear:` but not in `viewWillDisappear:`. Why should I hide `searchBar` in `viewWillDisappear:`? Thanks!